# Access to PHP array elements

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array when I used `var_dump()` this is the result I get:

```
  array(1) { ["GetVehicleConfigurationByVehicleIdResult"]=> array(9) { ["Id"]=> string(1)    "2" ["VIN"]=> NULL ["Year"]=> array(2) { ["Id"]=> string(4) "2006" ["Value"]=> string(4) "2006" } ["Make"]=> array(2) { ["Id"]=> string(1) "2" ["Value"]=> string(5) "Acura" } ["Model"]=> array(2) { ["Id"]=> string(1) "2" ["Value"]=> string(2) "TL" } ["Trim"]=> array(2) { ["Id"]=> string(6) "268650" ["Value"]=> string(12) "3.2 Sedan 4D" } ["Mileage"]=> string(6) "100000" ["OptionalEquipment"]=> array(1) { ["EquipmentOption"]=> array(35) { [0]=> array(13) { ["DisplayName"]=> string(19) "V6, VTEC, 3.2 Liter" ["VehicleOptionId"]=> string(3) "204" ["IsSelected"]=> string(4) "true" ["OptionTypeDisplayName"]=> string(6) "Engine" ["OptionGroupName"]=> string(3) "N/A" ["DisplayNameAdditionalData"]=> string(3) "N/A" ["ManufactureCode"]=> string(0) "" ["OptionAvailabilityDisplayName"]=> string(3) "N/A" ["IsDefaultConfiguration"]=> string(4) "true" ["DetailName"]=> string(3) "N/A" ["NonBoldName"]=> string(3) "N/A" ["Footer"]=> string(3) "N/A" ["SortOrder"]=> string(4) "1000" }
```

How I can get the elements from this array?
Some of the elements are complex, like they are array inside array.

That is the formatted print out of the array to understand better:

```
Array
(
[GetVehicleConfigurationByVehicleIdResult] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 2
        [VIN] => 
        [Year] => Array
            (
                [Id] => 2006
                [Value] => 2006
            )

        [Make] => Array
            (
                [Id] => 2
                [Value] => Acura
            )

        [Model] => Array
            (
                [Id] => 2
                [Value] => TL
            )

        [Trim] => Array
            (
                [Id] => 268650
                [Value] => 3.2 Sedan 4D
            )

        [Mileage] => 100000
        [OptionalEquipment] => Array
            (
                [EquipmentOption] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [DisplayName] => V6, VTEC, 3.2 Liter
                                [VehicleOptionId] => 204
                                [IsSelected] => true
                                [OptionTypeDisplayName] => Engine
                                [OptionGroupName] => N/A
                                [DisplayNameAdditionalData] => N/A
                                [ManufactureCode] => 
                                [OptionAvailabilityDisplayName] => N/A
                                [IsDefaultConfiguration] => true
                                [DetailName] => N/A
                                [NonBoldName] => N/A
                                [Footer] => N/A
                                [SortOrder] => 1000
                            )
```

I want to get: Id, VIN, Year, Make, Model, Trim,Mileage and OptionalEquipment and pass them as 1 single parameter to another method.

It solved:

```
$Id = $resultVehicleId['GetVehicleConfigurationByVehicleIdResult']['Id'];

$Year = $resultVehicleId['GetVehicleConfigurationByVehicleIdResult']['Year']['Value'];
```

Comment: Your google search term is [*"multi-dimensional"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+multi+dimensional+array&oq=php+multi+dimensional+array).

Comment: id = $array['Model']['id'];

Comment: `$arrayname['GetVehicleConfigurationByVehicleIdResult']['Id']` for example, or `$arrayname['GetVehicleConfigurationByVehicleIdResult']['Year']['Value']`

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just pass the array?

Comment: Well, it’s not as if you can’t just use any operator on the result of any expression. (Oh wait – this is PHP, isn’t it? Then I’ll add “since PHP 5.4”.) So feel free to chain subscripting. `$arr['GetVehicleEtcetera']['Id']`

Comment: `Year` won't work. It's an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. There are arrays inside of arrays here. And `var_dump` shows it very nicely so you can perfectly know how to navigate the levels of this multi-dimensional array.

If you want VIN just get `$array['GetVehicleConfigurationByVehicleIdResult']['VIN']`

For Year you need to get `$array['GetVehicleConfigurationByVehicleIdResult']['Year']['Value']`

I think you can guess the others now.

Answer (score 1):

They are just array elements no matter how deep you go so you can just reference them by name like below:

```
$id = $that_array['GetVehicleConfigurationByVehicleIdResult']['Id'];
```

Comment: $that_array is the variable you are placing in var_dump(). It was a placeholder name.

Answer (score 1):

```
$id = $array_name["GetVehicleConfigurationByVehicleIdResult"]['Id'];;
$vin = $array_name["GetVehicleConfigurationByVehicleIdResult"]['VIN'];
$year = $array_name["GetVehicleConfigurationByVehicleIdResult"]['Year']
$make = $array_name["GetVehicleConfigurationByVehicleIdResult"]['Make'];
$model = $array_name["GetVehicleConfigurationByVehicleIdResult"]['Model'];
$trim = $array_name["GetVehicleConfigurationByVehicleIdResult"]['Trim']['Value'];
$mileage = $array_name["GetVehicleConfigurationByVehicleIdResult"]['Mileage'];
$optional_equipment = $array_name["GetVehicleConfigurationByVehicleIdResult"]['OptionalEquipment']['EquipmentOption'][0]['DisplayName'];
```

Comment: I used this lines but it gave me error : Undefined variable: array_name

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity's sake I'm assuming this array is saved as $array.

You can access the data from the array like this:

```
$vin = $array['GetVehicleConfigurationByVehicleIdResult']['VIN'];
```

But you stated that you want to pass them all as a single parameter, so to do that you would probably want to just pass an array.

```
someFuntion($array['GetVehicleConfigurationByVehicleIdResult']);
```